# Why Git leave previous directories (like duplicate) after rename?

Tags: git

There is such a situation, let's say I have `dev` branch and such project struct `MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java`.
Then I make checkout `dev -> dev-test-first` and put in some files and make commit, now it looks like this

```
MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile3.java
```

Now, I make one more checkout from `dev -> dev-test-second` and firstly rename the `Foo` dir to `Boo` then delete `MyFile.java` and add `MyFile4.java` and commit it.

Result on `dev-test-second` br

```
MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Finally I make merge two of this branches `dev-test-first` and `dev-test-second` with main `dev` branch.

What am I expect to get?

This

```
MyProj/Boo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Boo/MyFile3.java 
MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Right? But actually this is what I get

```
MyProj/Foo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile3.java 
MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Instead of rename git hold two of this dirs `Boo` and `Foo` in spite of that fact that it was renamed.

Question is: why does this unexpected behavior happening?

Comment: I'm not really getting your question. Can you please post a short snippet and exact output you're getting?

Comment: @Maroun Case is - I have dev br -> make two branches more from dev `first and second` -> at first br I add 2 new files at second br I rename dir, delete file and add another file -> then merge this 2 branches `first and second` into `dev`. Then expected and actual result I published at the end of my question. Instead that all files exist in renamed dir - Boo, I see two dirs one is `Foo` (initial dir) and `Boo` renamed dir... Did you get what I mean?

Comment: To me this is expected—youre merging a branch with .../foo/stuff and .../bar/stuff. The renames are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git tracks content. Directories are tracked only as a path to tracked content, not as anything worth caring about themselves. Commits tell you the effects they're recording, your dev-test-second commit should have said ~delete Foo/MyFile.java; create Boo/MyFile4.java~.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about `MyFile.java` it was deleted, edited my question.  But anyway I expected to see all files under renamed dir `Boo`... So, it is means that let's say two devs works on diff branches and one of them rename a dir then make merge , so as a result someone have to make a refactor and put all the files under single dir, like `Boo` in my question, because files should not be in diff dirs in this case... Right?

Comment: If you keep in mind that directories are part of the path name, nothing more, you'll have an easier time of it.  The pain/gain ratio on implementing the machinery to help with this is too high, my sympathies for the surprise but Git's not going to help you with this, moving one file doesn't get merged as a command to move other files. You have to move them yourself.